# How to access C struct attributes from a Julia Ptr?

Tags: c, julia

Lets say there's a struct in C somewhere that I'm accessing in Julia:

```c
typedef struct ex {
    int a;
    int b;
} example;
```

If I ccall() a function that returns a Julia Ptr object `exptr` to the example struct, what is the equivalent to the c expressions `exptr->a` or `exptr->b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Julia struct that mirrors its definition, and then say that the `ccall` returns that struct:

```
julia> using Libdl

julia> const Clib = tempname();

julia> c_code = """
       typedef struct ex {
           int a;
           int b;
       } example;

       example f() {
           example ex;
           ex.a = 1;
           ex.b = 2;
           return ex;
       }
       """
"typedef struct ex {\n    int a;\n    int b;\n} example;\n\nexample f() {\n    example ex;\n    ex.a = 1;\n    ex.b = 2;\n    return ex;\n}\n"

julia> open(`gcc -fPIC -xc -shared -o $(Clib * "." * Libdl.dlext) -`, "w") do io
           print(io, c_code)
       end

julia> struct Example
           a::Cint
           b::Cint
       end

julia> ccall((:f, Clib), Example, ())
Example(1, 2)
```

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using someone else's library. I don't mind forking it and making the changes myself, but is there a way to do this without modifying pre-existing code?

Comment: You don't need to modify the C code; you just need to write a Julia struct that mirrors the C code.  The first four prompts I show here are just to setup an example C library.  It's the last two that are relevant to your case.

Comment: The library I'm referring to is a sparse Julia wrapper for a C library. It looks like it implemented what you're describing in a clunky way, so I'm going to fork it and fix it. Thanks for your help!